# Swift invalid escape sequence in literal

Tags: swift

If I try to compile I receive "invalid escape sequence in literal" error because of `"\;"` but if I try to use `"\\;"` or `"\u{005C};"` 
I receive error `find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"` like I am not passing the backslash character

```
@IBAction func button1(_ sender: NSButton) {

    let path = "/usr/bin/find"
    let arguments = ["folder_path","-name","'*.docx'","-print","-exec","zip","'{}'.zip","'{}'","\;"]

    sender.isEnabled = false

    let task = Process.launchedProcess(launchPath :path, arguments: arguments)

    task.waitUntilExit()

    sender.isEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: What happens if you just omit the backslash completely?

Comment: for some reason xcode doesn't return any error but the command doesn't do anything, in fact the same command without \ on a terminal return find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+" . I know for shure this command must end with \; on a terminal

Comment: Right, but that is because in the terminal the shell eats the backslash before the `find` command can get at it. But here you are not in a shell parser; the arguments are separate strings. In the same way, I wonder whether the single quotes around `{}` are needed.

Comment: quotes around {} are not needed. But for some reason is doesn't do what it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Rob says (and as I had gently suggested in my comments), you are not in a shell, so you do not need any special quoting or backslashing.

There's no way I am going to execute a zip command on my machine, so I tested like this:

```
let task = Process()
task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/find"
task.arguments = 
    ["/Users/matt/Desktop", "-name", "*.mp3", "-exec", "echo", "{}", ";"]
```

With appropriate pipe configured, I ran the task and read from the pipe and sure enough, we found the one *mp3* file on my Desktop. Notice that *no* arguments are single-quoted or backslashed.

Answer (score 1):

You've added a bunch of shell-escapes when you're not passing this to a shell. For example:

```
"'*.docx'"
```

In this context, this literally mean `'*.docx'`, with the extra `'`. Those are included when you call the shell because otherwise the shell would expand the `*`. But again, no shell. So nothing is removing them for you. Same issue for the `;`. You just want a `;`, which is required by `-exec`. But there's no shell in the way, so you don't need a backslash because nothing would eat the `;`.

You mean:

```
let arguments = ["folder_path","-name","*.docx","-print","-exec","zip","{}.zip","{}",";"]
```

Comment: And is exactly what I had suggested.