# Running command line tool from Swift

Tags: swift, command-line

I want to incorporate a command line tool in my MacOS project in Swift. Basically I'd wish I could just pass the arguments and options in String form just like I would use the tool from a normal command line. But I have no idea where to actually start. Tips are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as arguments and options to the command line are concerned, you are looking for the [Process class](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/process) (known in Objective-C as NSTask).

Comment: This question shows the user working out how to call the `find` tool: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41538445/swift-invalid-escape-sequence-in-literal Of course if the tool is in your application bundle you'd have to work out its path, but that's trivial.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed :)